# What is wrong with this C++ recursion function of mine?

Tags: c++, recursion

first off sorry if the code comes out weird. Looks good after following the instructions for sharing here but it's my first time. Anyways, I have a class assignment where I need to create a recursive function that when given an array returns the sum of it's elements. I have found solutions that work online but they seem similar enough to mine. My code runs but the sum comes out as a giant integer, specifically with the code below the output of sum is -858993459. I've seen some similar things before and I tried going over what might be a common mistake but I at least failed to find anything. Please help explain what is going on, I would like to use the parameters I've set (I've seen it other ways as stated) because I want my code to be at least somewhat unique. Thanks in advance everyone!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <array>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int getSumOfElements(int intArray[], int firstElement, int lastElement, int sum) {
    if (firstElement > lastElement)
        return sum;
    else {
        sum += intArray[firstElement] + intArray[lastElement];
        getSumOfElements(intArray, firstElement + 1, lastElement - 1, sum);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int sum = 0, lastElement, firstElement = 0;
        int exampleArray1[] = { 1, 5, 6, 12, 7 }, exampleArray2[] = { 3, -5, -16, 4, 10, 1, 7 };

        lastElement = sizeof(exampleArray1) / sizeof(exampleArray1[0]);
        sum = getSumOfElements(exampleArray1, firstElement, lastElement, sum);
        cout << "The sum of all elements in Array1 are " << sum << endl;

        lastElement = sizeof(exampleArray2) / sizeof(exampleArray2[0]);
        sum = getSumOfElements(exampleArray2, firstElement, lastElement, sum);
        cout << "The sum of all elements in Array2 are " << sum << endl;

        system("pause");
   }
```

Comment: You aren't assigning the recursive call to getSumOfElements to anything.  Also as written it does not have a closing brace so something must have happened when you copied it here.

Comment: This is likely one of many problems, but if you only add the firstElement and lastElement of the array, how are you summing the array of elements?

Comment: Also, with an odd number of array elements, you wind up counting the middle item twice.  You should add a check that if first == last, then only add that element once.

Comment: initially lastElement will be outside of your array (since the last valid array element is at (# of elements in array - 1).

Comment: The closing bracket was a typo on this end, I fixed it but it was there in my original program. And thank you for pointing out that odd # of elements. I was using an old code I had that simply swapped the elements and it wasn't a problem then. And thank you so much for pointing that out how my variable lastElement just needs to subtract one. Believe it or not I had that from the old code but removed it when I clearly wasn't thinking xD Thanks again everyone!

Comment: @DBug I added the check (and all the other little fixes that have been mentioned) and I'm now getting integers of 27 and then 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing outside the array.

```
int lastElement = sizeof(exampleArray1) / sizeof(exampleArray1[0]);
sum = getSumOfElements(exampleArray1, firstElement, lastElement, sum);
```

And then you do

```
sum += intArray[firstElement] + intArray[lastElement];
```

During the first call lastElement will index outside the array.
You should do

```
sum = getSumOfElements(exampleArray1, firstElement, lastElement - 1, sum);
```

That's why you get a "weird" integer value like -858993459.

Comment: Also `if(firstElement > lastElement)` should be `if(firstElement >= lastElement)`.

Comment: The general problem is that `lastElement` is actually the number of elements, and the index of the last element is `lastElement - 1`.

Comment: I ended up doing this, but it still seems to not work properly. Even after all the other changes have been made. Now I have it check for first > second then else if first == second else what I had before. I edited the question above to reflect the changes.

Comment: @JoshuaRG1993 careful with wholesale re-writes of questions. It makes all of the existing answers look goofy. Generally it is better to ask a new question than move the goal posts of the old one. For one thing, it is very hard to tell if this was a good answer I should upvote if I don't know the context under which it was written.

Comment: Okay, just to be clear you're suggesting to not edit the main question, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything in else conditions of you getSumOfElements, it that case garbage value used for return.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is needed. I tried with and without that 'return' before calling my function and the results are still the same.

Comment: you have other issues in your code. but main reason why your function return garbage is a lack of return statement. with it you'll have incorrect results, but not garbage.

Comment: @JoshuaRG1993 The return statements absolutely *are* needed! Try compiling with `-Wall -Werror` and your code will fail to compile since not all paths return an `int`

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll keep it in there. I must not be thinking clearly because I can't find a simple way to handle an odd or even array. So maybe I'll just put an if statement in there so there's two blocks of code, one for odd, other for even.

Comment: Just realized my else if first == last case added just first and not intArray[first]. So the code just isn't working for odd arrays now...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the help above ^^ All comments led to the answer but I unfortunately couldn't choose more than one. However, I reedited my original question to be as it was when first asked and below I will show the working code thanks to all the input.

```
    int getSumOfElements(int intArray[], int firstElement, int lastElement, int sum) {
        if (firstElement > lastElement)
            return sum;
        else if (firstElement == lastElement) {
            sum += intArray[firstElement];
            return sum;
        }
        else {
            sum += intArray[firstElement] + intArray[lastElement];
            return getSumOfElements(intArray, firstElement + 1, lastElement - 1, sum);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int sum1, sum2, sum3, lastElement, firstElement = 0;
        int exampleArray1[] = { 1, 5, 6, 12, 7 }, exampleArray2[] = { 3, -5, -16, 4, 10, 1, 7 },
            exampleArray3[] = { 1, 3, 5, 6 };

        lastElement = sizeof(exampleArray1) / sizeof(exampleArray1[0]) - 1;
        sum1 = getSumOfElements(exampleArray1, firstElement, lastElement, 0);
        cout << "The sum of all elements in Array1 are " << sum1 << endl;

        lastElement = sizeof(exampleArray2) / sizeof(exampleArray2[0]) - 1;
        sum2 = getSumOfElements(exampleArray2, firstElement, lastElement, 0);
        cout << "The sum of all elements in Array2 are " << sum2 << endl;

        lastElement = sizeof(exampleArray3) / sizeof(exampleArray3[0]) - 1;
        sum3 = getSumOfElements(exampleArray3, firstElement, lastElement, 0);
        cout << "The sum of all elements in Array3 are " << sum3 << endl;

        system("pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have made modifications to your question since you initially asked it, but try to leave your question as is for now.

There are a couple problems with your recursive function (original below):

```
int getSumOfElements(int intArray[], int firstElement, int lastElement, int sum) {
if (firstElement > lastElement)
    return sum;
else if (firstElement == lastElement)
    sum += firstElement;
else {
    sum += intArray[firstElement] + intArray[lastElement];
    getSumOfElements(intArray, firstElement + 1, lastElement - 1, sum);
    }
}
```

In its simplest form, there are two main things with recursion: the *base case*, and the *recursive case*. You have 2 base cases (which is fine):

1. When you are currently in a situation where your firstElement index is greater than your lastElement index (done with even sized array)
2. When your firstElement index is the same as your last element index (done with odd sized array)

The only time you should be doing the actual logic is in the *recursive* case. Therefore, your base cases should simply be returning `0` (for the first), or `intArray[firstElement]` (the value) for the second. Why? Because your function only returns the sum of the integers from firstElement to lastElement. If you've crossed, then you've already added all the numbers. If that index is the same, then the sum is just the value itself since that's the only one you still need to add in.

You only do the addition in the recursive case. What you are trying to say is that `getSumOfElements(..., first, last, sum)` is the same as `intArray[first] + intArray[last] + getSumOfElements(..., first+1, last-1, sum)` (add the ends and recursively add the rest by doing it again, always getting closer to the middle). Therefore, your recursive case should simply *add* the value in the array's firstElement index, the array's lastElement index, and the sum of the *rest* of the values, and return it.

A fixed version would look something like:

```
int getSumOfElements(int intArray[], int firstElement, int lastElement) {
    if (firstElement > lastElement) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (firstElement == lastElement) {
        return intArray[firstElement];
    }
    else {
        return intArray[firstElement] + intArray[lastElement] + getSumOfElements(intArray, firstElement + 1, lastElement - 1);
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to carry the sum through the recursive calls since you are returning the sum *so far* in each call. I really hope that sheds some more understanding on recursion.

Working sample: http://ideone.com/9xkMqT